# Verify Login using Realm in Android

Tags: android, realm

I have started learning **Realm** and I am creating **login/signUp** process using it.

I have successfully created both processes but I am **stuck** at one point.

I can only find **OR query** which will return true if either of value matches **i.e** `UserName` or `Password`. This is what I tried.

```
private  RealmResults<RegisterModal>getSingleRecord(String email,String password){
    return realm.where(RegisterModal.class)
                .contains("email",email)
                .or()
                .contains("password",password)
                .findAll();
}
```

This methods returns multiple records even when password of different users matches which will not lead to unique records.

So how to return a record if both email and password matches in realm?

Answer (score 1):

You should use an AND condition, just concatenating the `equalTo's`

```
    private RealmResults<RegisterModal>getSingleRecord(String email,String password){
        return realm.where(RegisterModal.class)
            .equalTo("email",email)
            .equalTo("password",password)
            .findAll();
    }
```

Consider that you should not have two or more users with the same email and password, then you can use findFirst() instead of findAll

Anyway, take a look [Realm official docs](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#conditions)

Comment: Thanks for this. I will give this a try . By the way is there anyway to stop duplicate records entry in database ?

Comment: The unique constraints is not available yet, but it's in the roadmap. Actually the only way to prevent duplicate records is to check them manually (just before the insertion) using a query with a concatenation of "equalTo"s on the fields that you need to be unique.
I hope I was helpful ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do 2 requests,

email and pass are bool variable.

```
private  RealmResults<RegisterModal>getSingleRecord(String email,String password) {
    email = realm.where(RegisterModal.class)
               .contains("email",email).findAll();
    if( email) {
        pass =   return realm.where(RegisterModal.class)
                         .contains("password",password)
                         .findAll(); 
        if( pass)
           return  realm.where(RegisterModal.class)
                         .contains("password",password)
                         .findAll();
    } else
        return null;
}
```

Comment: This is going to give errors on every line as where returns a `realmresult` and if statements doesn't work with Strings like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code snippet for **verifying user login and password** from `Realm`

```
private void checkUser(String email, String password) {
    RealmResults<UserDetails> realmObjects = mRealm.where(UserDetails.class).findAll();
    for (UserDetails myRealmObject : realmObjects) {
        if (email.equals(myRealmObject.getUser_email()) && password.equals(myRealmObject.getUser_password())) {
            Log.e("user_email", myRealmObject.getUser_email());
            showProgress(false);
            Intent iLogin = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(iLogin);
        } else {
            showProgress(false);
            Utility.showToastMessage(this, "Email/Password not matched");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are just looping through all the records and comparing username and password. While my question was more query oriented.

Comment: oh sorry, i didn't understand the question. my mistake